# How to create Google Sheet app that retrieves a mix of random words

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-arrays

I have a Google Sheet with a lot of columns, each of them containing words from a category. I would love to create a formula that can retrieve random words and put them together.
For example:

```
Colum 1 [cute, fav, dear, great]
Column 2 [love, friends, family, peers]
```

With the formula you get a random mix e.g. "cutelove", "favpeers", "greatlove", etc.

My knowledge is pretty basic, so I would love to know if this is even doable or at least where could I start. Really appreciate the help.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

[image: RANDOM]
you could use INDEX() and RANDBETWEEN(), see if [this example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12EoJ224h7etGQuEDUi0YYE3Q-TWGL3Nt9ieQ74z7GcE/edit?usp=sharing) satisfies you

Comment: This exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

The only problem is I keep getting the same 4 random combinations. I'll keep exploring and trying new things from here.

Thank you so much again, really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

If there are not too many categories to join, you can generate *all* possible combinations like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  flatten( 
    filter(A2:A, len(A2:A)) 
    & " " & 
    transpose(filter(B2:B, len(B2:B)))
  ) 
)
```

See column `G` in the [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12EoJ224h7etGQuEDUi0YYE3Q-TWGL3Nt9ieQ74z7GcE/edit#gid=0). This is a simple [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).

To get `10` random word pairs, use `sortn()`, like this:

```
=sortn( 
  flatten( 
    filter(A2:A, len(A2:A)) 
    & " " & 
    transpose(filter(B2:B, len(B2:B)))
  ), 
  10, 0, 
  randarray(counta(A2:A) * counta(B2:B)), 
  true  
)
```

See column `I` in the [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12EoJ224h7etGQuEDUi0YYE3Q-TWGL3Nt9ieQ74z7GcE/edit#gid=0).

If your intention is simply to generate a list of word pairs where no word is re-used, shuffle the two columns like this:

`=sort(A2:A, randarray(rows(A2:A)) * not(isblank(A2:A)), false)`

`=sort(B2:B, randarray(rows(B2:B)) * not(isblank(B2:B)), false)`

See columns `K:L` in the [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12EoJ224h7etGQuEDUi0YYE3Q-TWGL3Nt9ieQ74z7GcE/edit#gid=0).